# How to use ends-with in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying use ends-with in xslt for return any values. for example: I've this xml:

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>title1</TITLE>
        <ISSN>12313213</ISSN>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>title2</TITLE>
        <ISSN>67895776</ISSN>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>title3</TITLE>
        <ISSN>54363645</ISSN>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

and this static xml(book.xml):

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <VALUE>test title12</VALUE>
        <PRICE>1235,23</PRICE>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <VALUE>test title1</VALUE>
        <PRICE>345,23</PRICE>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

I need to verify if there's a book title in title xml. My code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="book" select="document('file:///E:/book.xml')"/>
<BOOKS> 
    <xsl:for-each select="$book/books/book">
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="VALUE"/>
        <xsl:variable name="price" select="ESTRATO"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//BOOKS">
            <xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
                <xsl:if test="ends-with($value, @TITLE)">
                    <BOOK>
                    <TITLE><xsl:value-of select="@TITLE"/></TITLE>
                    <ISSN><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></ISSN>
                    <PRICE><xsl:value-of select="$price"/></PRICE>
                    </BOOK>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</BOOKS>    
</xsl:template>
```

I wanna return when the book title ends-with in the tag VALUE in the xml books. Can anyone Help me? Thanks.

I've tried to use something like that [How to use contains in xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238489/how-to-use-contains-in-xslt) but doesn't worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use ends with in XSLT v1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848780/use-ends-with-in-xslt-v1-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. I *think* you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="book" select="document('file:///E:/book.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/BOOKS">
    <BOOKS> 
        <xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
            <BOOK>
                <xsl:copy-of select="TITLE | ISSN"/>
                <PRICE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$book/BOOKS/BOOK[ends-with(VALUE, current()/TITLE)]/PRICE"/>
                </PRICE>
            </BOOK>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </BOOKS>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that XML is case-sensitive: `book` does not match/select `BOOK`.